# Android Auto ScreenManager#popToRoot followed by a ScreenManager#push doesn't re-count the step

Tags: android-auto

For some reason I need to refresh the Car app. I tried to invoke [ScreenManager#popToRoot](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/ScreenManager#popToRoot()) first, then invoke [ScreenManager#push](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/ScreenManager#push(androidx.car.app.Screen)). However the step doesn't re-count, instead it is increased by one.
Is there a way for me to refresh the Car App?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? We have the same. In Screen A, we call `pushForResult` screen B. From screen B, we select a result and pass it back to Screen A. When A receives the result, it will start screen C. By logic C should be step 2 now, but the debugger shows it as step 3. The only solution is to add a slight delay before starting screen C.